# XYZ Esri tiles source with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, arcgis-server, xyz-tiles

I am trying to use XYZ Esri tile source with Openlayers for a cached service in Palestine Grid Coordinate System (EPSG:28191) as in [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz-esri.html). However openlayers fails request incorrect tiles which are always blank.
My cached ArcGIS service is https://portal.geomolg.ps/server/rest/services/AerialPhoto/AerialPhoto2019/MapServer
What might be the issue here?

Here is my code:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import View from 'ol/View';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';

var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        attributions:
          'Tiles © <a href="https://portal.geomolg.ps/server/rest/services/' +
          'AerialPhoto/AerialPhoto2019/MapServer">ArcGIS</a>',
        url:
          'https://portal.geomolg.ps/server/rest/services/' +
          'AerialPhoto/AerialPhoto2019/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
      }),
    }) ],
  view: new View({
    center: [-4839400.0, 6616800.0],
    zoom: 7,
  }),
});
```

With this configuration, Openlayers requests tiles that are not available like:
https://portal.geomolg.ps/server/rest/services/AerialPhoto/AerialPhoto2019/MapServer/tile/6/21/23

Comment: Try ZXY order in the URL

Comment: Did not work, thanks for the input.

Comment: OK, was worth the shot though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have a standard web mercator projection and tilegrid you need to set up a custom source by coping the projection and tilegrid details (origin, resolutions and extent) given in your link

```
import "ol/ol.css";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import View from "ol/View";
import XYZ from "ol/source/XYZ";
import Projection from "ol/proj/Projection";
import tileGrid from "ol/tilegrid/TileGrid";
import { getCenter } from "ol/extent";

var projection = new Projection({
  code: "EPSG:28191",
  units: "m"
});

var extent = [
  138649.32834740658,
  69334.55729794936,
  206649.25307599525,
  220465.75729794937
];

var map = new Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        attributions:
          'Tiles © <a href="https://portal.geomolg.ps/server/rest/services/' +
          'AerialPhoto/AerialPhoto2019/MapServer">ArcGIS</a>',
        url:
          "https://portal.geomolg.ps/server/rest/services/" +
          "AerialPhoto/AerialPhoto2019/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
        tileGrid: new tileGrid({
          origin: [-4839400.0, 6616800.0],
          resolutions: [
            529.1677250021168,
            264.5838625010584,
            132.2919312505292,
            66.1459656252646,
            33.86673440013547,
            16.933367200067735,
            8.466683600033868,
            4.233341800016934,
            2.116670900008467,
            1.0583354500042335,
            0.5291677250021167,
            0.26458386250105836,
            0.13229193125052918,
            0.06614596562526459
          ],
          extent: extent
        }),
        projection: projection
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: getCenter(extent),
    zoom: 8,
    projection: projection
  })
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-silence-ie6dj?file=/main.js:0-1598

Comment: I tried it and it worked out. Many Thanks!